# GET request from Django template working in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Tags: python, django, google-chrome, django-views, django-urls

I am pretty new to Gjango and Python. Here's what I have:

1. app/urls.py

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^upvote/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.upvote, name='upvote'),
   ]
   ```
2. views.py

   ```
   def upvote(request, id):
       print(id)
       try:
           link = Link.objects.get(id=id)
       except:
           print('err')
       link.vote = link.vote + 1
       print(link.vote)
       link.save()
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/news/')
   ```
3. And in template

   ```
   <a href="/news/upvote/{{l.id}}/">Up Vote</a>
   ```

Now, when I click in this link from Firefox, this works. The project's urls.py file contains `url(r'^news/', include('news.urls')),` so this link works. I get to see the two print statements' output from the views.py function and the value of this field increments in my database as expected. However, from Chromium, I see a very strange behaviour. The link works for a few times. Sometimes it works after I take a big pause. Then it just stops working. But from Firefox it works everytime. I restarted the server many times after clearing the `__pycache__` directories (don't know if that's relevant or not).

When I click from Firefox, I see the following in the Django's builtin development server's output every time:

```
[08/May/2016 01:46:58] "GET /news/upvote/2/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/May/2016 01:46:58] "GET /news/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2778
1
7
```

That 1 and 7 are the output of the print() statements. But when I click from Chromium, I see just this:

```
[08/May/2016 01:47:27] "GET /news/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2778
```

The view function is not being executed as you can see. How do I proceed to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing your cache in Chrome?

[How to Clear the Cache in Google Chrome](http://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-clear-cache)

Comment: No. Isn't this a server side issue? I don't think browser cache has anything to do with it. But I will clear Chromium's cache, just in case. And will let you know.

Comment: I've had similar behavior in Chrome working with the Jekyll server. Let me know if it makes a difference. Also try incognito mode in case you have plugins that are interfering.